# Site Hosted on G-Drive using DriveToWeb cannot find the Index File inside sub folders

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, web-hosting, google-drive-shared-drive

I am a newbie to HTML Development and hosted a hobby site on G-Drive using DriveToWeb.
The architecture of the Website is simple with the Root Folder having an Index.html with css and js files along with 2 sub-folders each having respective index.html and css files.

```
Architecture: 
Root Folder ==> Index.html + css + js files    
   Sub-Folder1 ==> Index.html + css + js files    
   Sub-Folder2 ==> Index.html + css + js files
```

I have kept root folder and all sub-folders as visible to all (Public on the Web) in sharing option for accessibility

When I browse my site using https://www.mysamplesite.com , it works perfectly fine & browser shows the Index Page of the Root Folder.

However when I browse my site using
https://www.mysamplesite.com/Sub-Folder1/ OR
https://www.mysamplesite.com/Sub-Folder2/ , I expect the browser to show me the Index page of the Sub-Folders which do not appear, instead I see the Index files of Root Folder without Css Styling.

To be more specific URL I tried https://www.mysamplesite.com/Sub-Folder1/Index.html , still it did not load

I tested this on Mobile Browser as well and same issue occurs.

I have to press Ctrl + Shift + R for the Index page of the sub-folder to load.
I cannot do this on mobile or every time I want the index file of sub-folders to load.

Do I need to make any changes to my .htaccess file ??

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)index([\.html]*)$ /$1 [R=302,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Request a suggestion for a corrective action to make the Index files of the Sub-Folders to load directly without need to do refresh every time.

Thanks in Advance
:)

Comment: You might want to see if the html5 <base> tag helps

Comment: @codin : can you please explain in detail how do you suggest the <base> tag to help here - thanks